# Diagnosing pixelation in mantaflow fire render

Tags: fire

I've been working on a fire composite whose settings keep a persistent pixelation even at high division resolutions and noise upres/strength (working in cycles, blender 2.91).

I have baked the domain as high as 1000 resolution divisions with noise settings varying around 2/2/2 and yet I still get this sort of blocky, blurry, structural pixelation. I'm generally happy with the render/glow/composite, but I feel like I'm missing something as far as how to dial in these bake settings correctly.

From what I've read, I understand the ideal resolution settings are usually capped at a few hundred division resolutions and then adding the detail in the noise, but I'm finding that 300 divisions is not salvaged by noise settings.

Current settings in this most recent take are 600 divisions, noise with an upres of 2, strength of 5. Looking at this, I'm skeptical this is the route since I'm used to the material bake of the fire showing the flame licks a little more clearly pre-render (left hand of the 3d viewport in image 1) rather than this sort of aerosolized fuzz, but I also think the general structure of the flames are actually good in the render, just noticeably low-quality.

One thought I've had: I am working in a 3d scale of about 1 square meter. I notice most examples of this type of flame are done larger, so I'm curious if I just need to break all the rules and just keep going even higher divisions.

[image]

[image]